# Increase the caret cursor size in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

Is there a way to increase the size for the caret cursor in VS Code? I'm on MacOS.

I find it hard to see:

[image: Purple]

Comment: `"editor.cursorStyle": "block"`?

Comment: and try     "editorCursor.foreground": "#ff0",  in the   "workbench.colorCustomizations"

Comment: The "caret" isn't a cursor, @Musa. It signifies the deletion of a line above the caret.

Comment: @Alex that helps tremendously, thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In settings.json try the following:

```
"editor.cursorStyle": "line",
"editor.cursorWidth": 4
```

I found I could change the width from 1 to 7 and the cursor would get larger or smaller. Setting it to 0 did not have the effect of hiding it.

Comment: I set mine to 36 so it looks like a terminal cursor.

Comment: @Swim for that purpose it does make more sense to set your `"editor.cursorStyle": "block",`