# Increase the width of line cursor in Visual Studio Code's terminal emulator?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, editor

Is there a way to increase the width of the line cursor in terminal? It is way too small! I believe it is a integrated xterm.js, but I don't know if it is possible to change the settings and such. The [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) doesn't help either.

This question [Increase the caret cursor size in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47005048/increase-the-caret-cursor-size-in-vs-code) deals with cursor width of the **editor**, but it doesn't work for the **terminal**.

Comment: There is this setting: `terminal.integrated.cursorStyle`, `block` is the default though - as big as it gets, it is pretty big.  Make sure your setting is to `block`.

Comment: This feature just got added to xterm,js as option `cursorWidth` and will be part of the next release. Not when it will be in vscode and whether the settings gets exposed there.

Comment: I created a feature request here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87456. Thanks @jerch for confirming that. @Mark, I need it for `line` cursor because I prefer to have `line` (for editing) vs `block` (for vim mode) etc.

Comment: Lol I hope you could make sense of what I wrote (missing the word *sure*), anyway your issue ended up at the right person :)

Comment: @jerch, I didn't understand you earlier, but I now do :-).

Comment: @starball, thanks. I marked it as duplicate. I had this problem 2 years earlier though :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to confiure xterm's `cursorWidth` has been added to Visual Studio Code; it should be available in the next release.